# As on now Less Secure Apps stopped by Google, how to use PHPMailer to send email from GMail account?

Tags: php, phpmailer

Google gave facility "Less Secure Apps" to send email from third party apps.
As this settings disabled by google our PHPMailer stopped sending emails.
Anyone facing same issue ???

Comment: Google support page (found by googling "gmail less secure apps") already suggests alternatives: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en . App Password is probably the simplest to implement. Or of course you could switch to another SMTP provider, if you prefer. Have you done any research?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with ADyson above. Essentially just explaining what the link he posted suggests:

Dealt with this today. Just go to the gmail account, then go to Manage Your Google Account > Security.

From here enable 2-factor authentication, then once you have done You will see the "App passwords" option appear under the 2-step verification option. Click on this, name the device that you want to use, and then copy & paste the generated password that you are given into your code in place of the old password that you were using.

I've done this now for our office printer & the python script that I had to automatically deliver timesheets to everyone.